# Models inheritance, ForeignKey, get the correct object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problems with django models and inheritance.

I define a dashboard and a list of modules like this:

```
class Dashboard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class DashboardModule(models.Model):
    dashboard = models.ForeignKey(Dashboard, related_name='modules')
    position_line = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    position_col = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def render(self):
      return 'hehe'

class Custom1DashboardModule(DashboardModule):
    #custom fields and methods
    def render(self):
      return 'toto'

class Custom2DashboardModule(DashboardModule):
    #custom fields and methods
...
```

I use the code like this:

```
dashboard = Dashboard()
dashboard.name = 'my dashboard'
dashboard.save()

module = Custom1DashboardModule()
module.dashboard = dashboard
module.save()

module = Custom2DashboardModule()
module.dashboard = dashboard
module.save()
```

then when I do

```
dashboard.modules.all()
```

I get a list of DashboardModule and not custom. I understand why but this is a problem.

Is there a solution to fix my problem ? Maybe I have to rethink the architecture ?

Comment: show more of your code. Like this we don't understand what the problem is. What is `dashboard` in `dashboard.modules.all()`? What is the contents of the `Dashboard` model?

Comment: thank, I have fixed and improved the question.

Comment: so where is `modules` on `dashboard` defined? I don't see it nowhere in your code.

Comment: 'modules' is defined in the module with the keyword related_name:
    dashboard = models.ForeignKey(Dashboard, related_name='modules')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django won't automatically downcast models. I found a post by [Jeff Elmore on the automatic downcasting of models](http://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/) helpful. In it he mentions [django-model-utils](http://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/src)  and  [django-polymorphic-models](http://code.google.com/p/django-polymorphic-models/) as well as providing his own solution (https://bitbucket.org/Enzondio/django-model-utils/overview).

Comment: Thank you, the solution is perfect.

on the link https://bitbucket.org/Enzondio/django-model-utils/overview search 'InheritanceManager'

Answer (score 0):

This looks very weird. Why would you work with inheritance here? In django every model is a table in your database (or almost every model is, unless it has `abstract=True` in its meta settings). Your query yields the right results (assuming you have changed the standard `objects` manager for the `modules` you are using here), because the only things related to Dashboard is DashoardModule. Rethink the architecture in function of what you want your database to look like.

Check the following links:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/
- http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html